# Prolog unifies a variable with a term then forgets the unification

Tags: prolog

I have the following predicate which I have written for recognising when two lists are the same except the two elements at indices `I1` and `I2` are swapped:

```
swapped(I1, I2, List, NewList) :-
    % The lists are the same length and the two indices are swapped.
    same_length(List, NewList),
    nth0(I1, List, V1), nth0(I2, List, V2),
    nth0(I1, NewList, V2), nth0(I2, NewList, V1),
    % All the other indices remain the same.
    proper_length(List, Length), Lim is Length - 1,
    numlist(0, Lim, Indices),
    forall((member(I, Indices), I \= I1, I \= I2),
           (nth0(I, List, V), nth0(I, NewList, V))).
```

The following `swipl` output demonstrates my issue:

```
?- swapped(0, 1, [1,2,3], L).
L = [2, 1, _G5035].

?- swapped(0, 1, [1,2,3], [2,1,3]).
true.

?- swapped(0, 1, [1,2,3], [2,1,4]).
false.
```

Why does it return a variable for the third element rather than just `3`, given that it can recognise that `3` is the only correct term? These are the last four parts of the trace where the unification happens and is then forgotten:

```
   Call: (10) lists:nth0(2, [2, 1, _G6121], 3) ? creep
   Exit: (10) lists:nth0(2, [2, 1, 3], 3) ? creep
^  Exit: (8) forall(user: (member(_G6145, [0, 1, 2]), _G6145\=0, _G6145\=1), user: (nth0(_G6145, [1, 2, 3], _G6162), nth0(_G6145, [2, 1, _G6121], _G6162))) ? creep
   Exit: (7) swapped(0, 1, [1, 2, 3], [2, 1, _G6121]) ? creep
```

I don't doubt there's a better way to swap two elements (perhaps recursively) but I would like to know why this is happening and how to fix it; I'm clearly lacking in some Prolog knowledge.

Thanks!

Comment: `forall/2` is only for testing sufficiently instantiated goals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2)/2 is a so called '[failure driven loop](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pbrna/prologbook/node95.html)'. Then instantiations are undone between cycles.

In SWI-Prolog, there is [foreach](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foreach/2)/2, that fixes the problem with your first query.

```
...
numlist(0, Lim, Indices),
foreach((member(I, Indices), I \= I1, I \= I2),
       (nth0(I, List, V), nth0(I, NewList, V))).
```

Test:

```
?- swapped(0, 1, [1,2,3], L).
L = [2, 1, 3].
```

In SWI-Prolog, sometime the better way to understand a builtin is to inspect the source. You can see that foreach/2 is a fairly complicated predicate... from swipl prompt, try `?- edit(foreach).`, or follow the source link from the doc page (the circled [:-](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/aggregate.pl?show=src#foreach/2)).

Comment: Nice to see use of `edit(foreach).` Please keep those hints coming.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I thought I'd tried foreach though I didn't understand the difference, I guess I hadn't tried it with the final version of the predicate. Thanks as well for the `edit` tip.

Comment: `\=/2` ---> `=\=/2`